# Combining lists into one list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
datalist = [{'data': [-2,-9,-13,-10,-5,-2,9,-5]},{'data': [-2,-9,-13,-10,-5,-2,9,-5]}]
results = []
results = [line['data'] for line in datalist]
print(results)
```

The result is `[[-2, -9, -13, -10, -5, -2, 9, -5], [-2, -9, -13, -10, -5, -2, 9, -5]]`
But I want `[-2, -9, -13, -10, -5, -2, 9, -5, -2, -9, -13, -10, -5, -2, 9, -5]`

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use one more iteration over inner list as:

```
results = [data for line in datalist for data in line['data']]
```